# Azure conditional access object ID translation

Tags: azure, powershell

Trying to create a simple conditional access policy report,

```
$Policies = Get-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy
$Policies[1].Conditions.Users.IncludeGroups
```

These group object ID's can be resolved using:

```
Get-AzureADObjectByObjectId -ObjectIds xxxx-xxxxx
```

But how to resolve, for example, locations?

```
$Policies[1].Conditions.Locations.ExcludeLocations
```

Could not find the location ID's using `Get-AzureADObjectByObjectId`.

Any ideas appreciated ...

Comment: What exact output are you getting from `$Policies[1].Conditions.Locations.ExcludeLocations`?

Comment: This is the output,

$Policies[1].Conditions.Locations.ExcludeLocations

c28114ef-a7cc-4595-810d-94e7fb0b4050

6d6469e1-d5e9-46e6-9173-831b7d6e7b84

a013a671-65ec-47d2-9e35-1b079550655d

Comment: Try `$Policies[1].Conditions.Locations.ExcludeLocations |% { Get-AzureADMSNamedLocationPolicy -PolicyId $_ }`

Answer (score 0):

For the location id's you need to query the `namedLocations` API rather than the directory itself. For this, use `Get-AzureADMSNamedLocationPolicy`:

```
$Policies[1].Conditions.Locations.ExcludeLocations |ForEach-Object { 
    Get-AzureADMSNamedLocationPolicy -PolicyId $_
}
```